# How to test parameter's type of a function in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test type of parameter of a function in Jest. How can I do that?

```
export const mainResponseArray = (apiResponse) => {
const successfulRequests = [];
const failedRequests = [];
apiResponse.map((response) => {
  const responseObj = {};
  if (response.status === 'fulfilled') {
    responseObj.status = response.status;
    successfulRequests.push(responseObj);
  } else {
    responseObj.status = response.status;
  }
  return '';
});
  return { successfulRequests, failedRequests };
};
```

Here the function `mainResponseArray` taking the `apiResponse` as parameter which is an array of objects (multiple API responses will come in `apiResponse`). I want to test it using Jest. How can I test it? I am expecting the `apiResponse` as an array of objects.

Currently I am trying to test using this piece of code

```js
const { mainResponseArray } = require('./myFiles');

it('should throw if argument "element" is not array of objects', () => {
  mainResponseArray.forEach((elementId) => {
    elementId.toBeInstanceOf(Object);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please share how you are already testing this in Jest? It's far easier to help if you have a [mcve] we can see.

Comment: What do you mean test the _type_ of the parameter? It's up to the caller, not the callee, to send the right type of thing (in this case, something with a map method, which you seem to be misusing).

Comment: Api response is async feature. You cannot map it like regular array. Check out Promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all?retiredLocale=tr

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox, I have added how I am testing currently

Comment: Hi @OsmanCorluk, async/await is already there is other file, this is just the response array of the all the API calls

Comment: The `mainResponseArray` function never throws?

Comment: No, it was not proper response what I needed, anyway now I changed the approach and not needed it anymore. Thanks everyone for comments.